# TextView with layout_height="wrap_content" not wrapping exactly

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with `layout_height="wrap_content"` in XML-layout, but the text is not at the very top of the textfield, there are some pixels padding.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:background="@color/text_orange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla bla bla"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
```

How can I achieve that the textfield is wrapped exactly around the text without any padding between the text and the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in your TextView.

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

By default the fontPadding is true.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Try to set negative margins on your layout and let me know if this fixed your issue.

`android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"`

Comment: yes, it did - I know now what's causing this: e.g. Å looks good, but A doesn't (= needs negative margin)

Comment: What is it causing the padding ?

Comment: the textview includes a padding that letters like Â, Å, Ó, ... are exactly layed out at the top. As my text doesn't have accents there's always a padding included

Comment: Ah, now I see. Happy coding fella.

Answer (score 1):

You can set.

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```